# How to create New user identity out side from Account controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I have merged my database with MVC asp.net Identity database and i want to creat a new user using asp.net identity from other controller ,but i could not successfully add the user even my code work without error this is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,EmailConfirmed,Password,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] AspNetUsers aspNetUsers)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //    ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());

        //    var manager =   HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager<User>>();
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>();
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = aspNetUsers.Email, UserName = aspNetUsers.UserName };
         var result=   manager.CreateAsync(user, aspNetUsers.PasswordHash);
        manager.Create(user, aspNetUsers.Password);
        //    db.AspNetUsers.Add(aspNetUsers);
        //    db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(aspNetUsers);
}
```

Comment: You should be able to reach the `ApplicationUserManager`....check if you have different namespaces between your controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
ApplicationUserManager _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
var manger = _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = aspNetUsers.Email, UserName = aspNetUsers.UserName };
var usmanger= manger.Create(user, aspNetUsers.PasswordHash);
```